# react native redux connect undefined function

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

I have below codebase

Expo link

https://snack.expo.io/@mparvez19861/redux-example

**app.js**

```
 <Provider store={store}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Navigator />
                </View>
            </Provider>
```

**Navigator.js**

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  // { SignIn: SignInScreen }
  // SignIn: { screen: EmailPwdLogin }
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Signup: { screen: SignupScreen },
  });
const drNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {

    Screen2: {
        screen: Screen2
      },
     SignOut: {
      screen: SignOutScreen
    }
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    // screendesign: screendesign,
    SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
    App: drNav,
    AuthStack: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
  }
));
```

**login.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUserData, watchUserLogin } from '../redux/app-redux';



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userData: state.userData,
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getUserData: (user) => { dispatch(getUserData(user)) },
    };
}

class LoginScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userData: null,
            email: "",
            password: "",
        };
    }

    onLoginPress = () => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then((user) => {
                //this.state.userData = user;
                this.setState({ userData: user })
                this.onGetUserData(user);
               // this.props.navigation.navigate("friendsOnWay");
            }, (error) => { Alert.alert(error.message); });
    }

    onGetUserData = (user) => {
        this.props.getUserData(user);
    }

    onCreateAccountPress = () => {
        // var navActions = NavigationActions.reset({
        //     index: 0,
        //     actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: "Signup"})]
        // });
        // this.props.navigation.dispatch(navActions);
        // this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup");
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ paddingTop: 50, alignItems: "center" }}>

                <Text>Login</Text>

                <TextInput style={{ width: 200, height: 40, borderWidth: 1 }}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ email: text }) }}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                />

                <View style={{ paddingTop: 10 }} />

                <TextInput style={{ width: 200, height: 40, borderWidth: 1 }}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ password: text }) }}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                />

                <Button title="Login" onPress={this.onLoginPress} />
                <Button title="Create account..." onPress={this.onCreateAccountPress} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen);
```

Throwing error

> TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0,
>   _react.useMemo)')
>
> This error is located at:
>       in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
>       in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:784)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at StackViewLayout.js:783)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at StackViewLayout.js:782)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:153)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:69)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:153)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:59)
>       in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:57)
>       in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:27)
>       in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:860)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at screens.native.js:83)
>       in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:311)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:153)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.js:307)
>       in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.js:300)
>       in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
>       in withOrientation (at StackView.js:79)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at Transitioner.js:214)
>       in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
>       in StackView (created by Navigator)
>       in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
>       in KeyboardAwareNavigator (created by SceneView)
>       in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
>       in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
>       in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
>       in NavigationContainer (at App.js:94)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at App.js:93)
>       in Provider (at App.js:92)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
>
> This error is located at:
>       in NavigationContainer (at App.js:94)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at App.js:93)
>       in Provider (at App.js:92)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33) ConnectFunction
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-redux\lib\components\connectAdvanced.js:131:41
>   updateFunctionComponent
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11441:29
>   updateSimpleMemoComponent
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11352:4
>   updateMemoComponent
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11224:8
>   beginWork
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12824:8
>   performUnitOfWork
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16075:21
>   workLoop
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16115:41
>   renderRoot
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16219:15
>   performWorkOnRoot
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17198:17
>   performWork
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17099:24
>   performSyncWork
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17060:14
>   requestWork
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16925:19
>   scheduleWork
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16724:16
>   scheduleRootUpdate
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17413:15
>   updateContainerAtExpirationTime
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17447:28
>   updateContainer
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17537:4
>   render
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18191:20
>   renderApplication
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:59:34 run
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:101:10
>   runApplication
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:195:26
>   __callFunction
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:366:47
>   
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106:26
>   __guard
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:10
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       D:\Rnd\React Native\Project\WhoAroundMe\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105:17

What I am doing wrong please help

Comment: Is that your stacktrace or is there more?

Comment: Full error updated

Comment: Does your redux provider wrap around the root navigator(`react-navigation`)?

Comment: I have updaetd the navigator file

Comment: When does the error occur i.e on click of a button or when you just run the app?

Comment: On just run only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191571/discussion-between-10101010-and-md-parvez-alam).

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried to use react-redux v6 then I get another error "Unable to resolve module" ... can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: I update my react version and its working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 7.0.1 of redux-sagas  "now require a minimum React version of 16.8.4 or higher."

Comment: Do you mean react-redux?

Comment: Did I mean react-redux? Nope

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem i used react-native version 0.58.6 and react-redux version 6.0.1 and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error. I updated my versions for react and react native to last version as well as redux and react-redux. It's solved then. Hope works for you too.